# Select a specific item from an array in a Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

If I have the following 2 arrays bound to a compiled [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) template:

```
questions: [
    {id:1, text:'question1', answers: [
        {id: 1, text:'answer1'},
        {id: 2, text:'answer2'}
    ]},
    {id:2, text:'question2', answers: [
        {id: 1, text:'answer3'},
        {id: 2, text:'answer4'}
    ]}
],
userAnswers: [
    {questionId:1, answerId:2}
]
```

I would rather not change the data structure and need to do the following (pseudo-code):

```
for each (question in questions) 
    render question text
    render user answer text
```

(note that there may be a question without an answer)

If I use 'each' in my Handlebars template:

```
{{#each question}}
```

Is there a way to get the answer id from the userAnswers object?

Then map this back to questions to get the text?

e.g. is there some kind of selector syntax such as:

```
{{../userAnswers[questionId=id].answerId}}
```